# why VSTO Outlook Add-in and Office JS add-in conversationId is not same?

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

why VSTO Outlook Add-in and Office JS add-in `conversationId` is not same how can I get same in VSTO like in javascript

but javascript `conversationId` is different then VSTO

using JavaScript mail `conversationId = AQQkADAwATNiZmYAZC01OGM3LTFhN2ItMDACLTAwCgAQAEDQN/vy31NNlzWXFRhAMCo=`

using vsto mail `conversationId = 0776E8C6D9B30D44A4EA16BE9211AA81`

using this I am getting conversationId in Office JS add-in

`const conversationId = Office.context.mailbox.item.conversationId;`

and using this I am getting conversationId in vsto add-in

```
  // Method to get the Conversation ID of the selected email
  private string GetSelectedEmailConversationId()
  {
      string conversationId = "";

      try
      {
          Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
          Outlook.Explorer explorer = outlookApp.ActiveExplorer();

          // Check if any item is selected
          if (explorer.Selection.Count > 0)
          {
              object selectedItem = explorer.Selection[1];
              if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem)
              {
                  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                  // Get the Conversation ID of the selected email
                  conversationId = mailItem.ConversationID;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please select an email.", "No Email Selected", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
              }
          }
          else
          {
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please select an email.", "No Email Selected", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          // Handle any errors
          System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }

      return conversationId;
  }
```

Comment: I also tried this but not same like javascript
`conversationId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mailItem.ConversationID));`

Comment: Try posting this as an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConversationId` property is a computed value, derived from other conversation-related properties, that identifies a message as belonging to a specific conversation. This property is computed by the application, server or client. It seems `OfficeJS` uses an Exchange computed property value while in Outlook (VSTO) you got a local value computed in Outlook (Extended MAPI).

Comment: Actually I need a mail id that is same in both side `VSTO` and `OfficeJS `

Comment: Try posting this as an issue to github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Comment: Already done [issue link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-reference/issues/1856)